# Jquery disable href after click and enable after 3 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery

my site have many `<a target="_blank">` will call api

I need to prevent double click on those button.

here is what I did

```
.disable {
    pointer-events: none;
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('disable');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('disable');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

because its target blank, therefor I need those href still able to work after few sec.

Somehow I just not able to enable those button again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside `setTimeout` is not the same as `this` outside it.

You can do something like:

```
var that = $(this);
that.addClass('disable');

setTimeout(function(){
  that.removeClass('disable');
}, 3000);
```

And then it should work

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like `jQuery('.disable').click(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault() })`. This would only stop clicks, though. Tabbing until hitting enter or some other interactions might still trigger a visit.

A "safer" way might be to use JS to temporarily shift the href attribute out and back in later (like storing the original href target somewhere, and replacing with `javascript:return false;` or removing the href attribute completely

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping problem.  Inside the `setTimeout`, `this` no longer refers to the anchor element you're trying to modify; instead it points to the browser window (because `setTimeout` is a method on the `window` object).

The classic way to solve this is by capturing `this` in a separate variable which will still be in scope within the `setTimeout`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('disable');
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(self).removeClass('disable');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

```css
.disable {background-color:#F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Or in ES6 you could use a fat arrow function, which doesn't change the variable scope:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('disable');
        setTimeout(()=>{
            $(this).removeClass('disable');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

```css
.disable {background-color:#F00}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a>
```